# How to save a object in Jackrabbit repository having map as one field?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I have a pojo class (`Location`) which have a property as

```
@Collection(jcrType="nt:map") Map<String, String> map;
```

Now when i am trying to insert a Location objeect in jackrabbit repository.
It is giving error as:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.exception.IncorrectPersistentClassException: Class of type: java.lang.String has no descriptor. 
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.mapper.impl.AbstractMapperImpl.getClassDescriptorByClass(AbstractMapperImpl.java:203) 
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.manager.collectionconverter.impl.DefaultCollectionConverterImpl.doInsertCollection(DefaultCollectionConverterImpl.java:116) 
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.manager.collectionconverter.impl.AbstractCollectionConverterImpl.insertCollection(AbstractCollectionConverterImpl.java:80)
```

How i can save a object in the repository?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem. Take a look at this link
http://osdir.com/ml/users.jackrabbit.apache.org/2009-06/msg00129.html

By default, `@Collection` is not supporting maps based on `<String, String>`,
the elements have to be beans based classes, not primitive types. If you
want to use primitive types or wrapper classes, you have to use the
collection converter `MultiValueCollectionConverterImpl`.

Though the problem was solved I am still not sure how the values are stored.